# Android source code building in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, linux, compiler-errors, ubuntu-12.04, android-4.4-kitkat

My friend has downloaded Android Kitkat source code and he has built it in his machine.Later he gave me that tar file of Kikat source code, I took that source code and when i tried to build it i got following below compilation issue

make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/media/XXXXXX/kitkat/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/4.7/include/stdarg.h', needed by`../../../out/target/product/XXXXX/XXX/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXX/XXXXX/init.o'.  Stop.

I have also installed all utilities such as zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev but still i am facing the same issue
So i just want to know that will i face any problem if i directly build downloaded source file from other machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tar file you got from your friend has the object files built for his system, so you may need to do clean build.

Comment: Thanks a lot Vijeth PO.After clean build it worked for me.